# How to get the pids of a process running through Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, pid, macos-catalina

I wanted to attach the lldb server to the Xcode processes. When I try to get the list of PIDs I am not able to get the exact PIDs of those processes. Is there any way available?

Can we list the PIDs of Xcode processes? How to list the actual PIDs of Xcode processes on the Terminal.

[image]

In the above image, you can see that I wanted to get the actual PID of a StarterDemo application which is running through Xcode. How to get it through Command line/Terminal.

Comment: What is your `Launch` type: `Automatically` or `Wait for the executable to be launched` ?

Comment: Your process for your StarterDemo application is listed at the top of your screenshot, 633. It says it's already being debugged.

Comment: @Olha my launch type is automatically.

Comment: @TheFunk Yes, I wanted to attach my lldb server through the command line to that process. I am not yet sure if I can do that.